# Assign value in ng-repeat with function in controller (ANGULAR JS)

Tags: angularjs, controller, init, assign

I'm trying to assign a value with function in a ng-repeat.
This ng repeat show a list of users ID. and i'm trying to call a function who return name by users id and print the name of the user.

i have tried with ng-init but it doesnt work.

```
<label ng-repeat="id in listOfUsersID">
  <p ng-init='text=getNameByID(id.id_user)''> Name is {{text}} 
  </p>
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not helpful.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ Use standard debugging techniques to isolate the problem.

Comment: Don't use ng-init. the documentation clearly say it shouldn't be used, and says what you should do instead: add code to your controller, that provides the data that the view needs: an array of users.

Comment: even if this were to work, this would be highly inefficient.  You shouldn't add functions to elements in an `ng-repeat`, since `ng-repeat` isn't a single loop. It evaluates every single function on every iteration.  This is get exponentially worse the larger the list you are rendering is.  Instead, you should add the properties you want to render later to your object in the controller or service where you receive your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<label ng-repeat="id in listOfUsersID">
  <p> Name is {{ getNameByID(id.id_user) }}</p>
```

but in your controller, the function has to be in the $scope variable like so.

```
$scope.getNameByID = function(id){
    . . . 
    return(text);
}
```